# Getting trouble to fetch Top 3 students details Who attended class late

Tags: mysql, laravel

Actually i need those 3 students details who were late to attend their classes more than others.

for example there are 20 students, but each student were late like:

- a was 3 times late
- b was 5 times late
- c was 7 times late till 10th students.

So i need just top 3 students detail who were late.

I was using the query which were showing this error:

```
    GROUP BY `Date`
)

[Err] 1111 - Invalid use of group function
```

Query:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    student
WHERE
    ID IN
    (
        SELECT
            MAX( COUNT( SID ) )
        FROM
            attendance
        WHERE
            `Status`='Late'
        GROUP BY
            `Date`
    )
```

as i know i am using the max and count in a wrong way, please quid me how to use it or if someone write the correct query for me which helps me to get correct top 3 students records. thanks

[image: Student Table]

[image: Attendance Table]

Comment: Top x late is highest number of late occurrences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't care about what dates the students were late, then:

```
SELECT
    student.*,
    lateAttendanceOccurrencesBySid.*
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            `sid`,
            COUNT(*) AS occurrences
        FROM
            attendance
        WHERE
            `status` = 'Late'
        GROUP BY
            `sid`
    ) AS lateAttendanceOccurrencesBySid

    INNER JOIN student ON student.id = lateAttendanceOccurrencesBySid.sid

ORDER BY
    lateAttendanceOccurrencesBySid.occurrences DESC

LIMIT
    3
```

Comment: Hello, @Dai, will you help me to know how i can get results from same tables for daily late students?

Comment: @SaharaBaloch Please post a new question with example desired output. There are different ways to define "daily late" students.